# WIX Error - ICE03: Not a valid foreign key

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Currently using WIX v3.6.3303 for developing an installer project. We are using CruiseControl to auto build and test various changes before release. Here is the error we are getting back from the test build.

```
errorLGHT0204: ICE03: Not a valid foreign key; Table: XmlFile, Column: Value, Key(s): SetPlayerFileGenerator
```

We have configured features similar to this in the WIX project. In fact the implementation of our PlayerFileGenerator was copied from those other features. Here is the WIX element CruiseControl is breaking on.

```
<util:XmlFile
      Id="SetPlayerFileGenerator"
      Action="setValue"
      File="[#Web.config]"
      ElementPath='/configuration/applicationSettings***'
      Value="[#PlayerFileGen.exe]"
      Sequence="1" />
```

Again we have similar configurations for other feature sets, none of which have this issue. Has anyone encountered something like this before using WIX?

Answer (score 5):

You get this same error in WiX projects when you are trying to publish dialog controls that do not exist in the dialog you're trying to publish!  Example: The FeaturesDlg does not have a Next button, it has an Install button.  So if you simply change your  tag from CustomizeDlg to FeaturesDlg and left the Next button alone you'll get this error.