# MSI installation log says: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI installer with WiX 3.8 and I get this error in the MSI log when installing it:

```
MSI (s) (A0:60) [19:14:59:510]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
MSI (s) (A0:60) [19:14:59:510]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038
```

How can I fix this error?
Or maybe is it a known WiX/MSI issue that can be safely ignored?

My WiX script is extremely simple, it just installs a shell extension, so I have no idea where this error comes from.

From the GUI point of view, the installation finishes with no visible problem.

Comment: I think I misread your question, I will leave my answer in for now and delete it once you have had a chance to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Error 2205 in MSI is Database: [2]. Table does not exist: [3].and in this case it looks like there is no Error table in the MSI file. 2262 is Stream does not exist: [2]. System error: [3]. so it seems to be looking for a missing stream, AdminProperties, and if there was more of the log shown the context might tell you what's going on, a custom action or whatever. -2147287038 is just "not found", so it's just another "can't find it" error.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Improved?***: [**Different ways to create and interpret MSI logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890).

---

Try to enable **flush to log** by adding the <kbd>!</kbd>  character to the msiexec command line, like this:

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Your.log
```

This will **force the log file to be written to continuously** (flushed) instead of in batches. This ensures no log-buffer is lost due to a crashing package. This makes the whole install a lot slower, so only enable it when it is needed.

See **[msifaq.com](http://www.msifaq.com/)** for more details ([**logging faq entry**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm)). Search for ["**value 3**"](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) in the log file to find errors as explained by **Rob Mensching** (Wix & Orca author).

---

**Some other factors to consider:**

- Could **anti-virus software** or **desktop security software** be preventing file extraction?
- Is there plenty of **space on the system drive**?
- Are there any **errors found during a disk scan**?
- Have you tried running an **[admin install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512)** on the MSI to see if files extract properly that way?

Comment: What does validation say? In [Orca (bottom)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12101548/129130): Tools => Validate... [**See this thread for a sample**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24793670/129130).

Comment: Orca validation: all green