# Setup cannot set correct folder permission for %ProgramData%\MyFirm\MyApp on WinServer2012+.

Tags: windows, permissions, installation, windows-installer, installshield

There is my BasicMsi setup that installs an application (32bit) MyApp per-machine. The installer requires admin rights at startup.
The application MyApp is installed into the INSTALLDIR-folder selected by the Operator (by UI/CommadLine) and a `%ProgramData%\<MyFirm>\<MyApp>` structure is created with subfolders and files.
In the msi-table LockPermissions, permissions are set to modify (read/write/delete...) for folder `<MyApp>` for **LOCAL** user groups 'Administrators' and 'Users' (located by SID).
Files in `<MyApp>` and subfolders are used and modified by the application MyApp at runtime.
The setup installs the application on systems **from Win7 to Win10** and **from WinServer2003 to WinServer2016** (32/64; UAC on/off).
The application is launched by the Operator(s) with account in the local user groups 'Administrators' or 'Users' (**NOT** 'Run as admin').

***Problem:*** 
after installation on **WinServer2012 and WinServer2016 ONLY** (WinServer2008 is not checked; and **WinServer2003 - IS OK**) an Operator with account in the local group Administrators or Users does not have permissions to write/delete/create files in the folder `<MyApp>` and subfolders.
The result - the application does not work correctly (ONLY for WinServer2012 and WinServer2016).

***Help me, please, with Questions:***

- what is the difference in folders permissions under %ProgramData%, or what is the difference of rights of local built-in user groups ('Administrators' or 'Users') for Win10 (or WinServer2003) versus (WinServer2012 and WinServer2016) ?
- what else should be changed in the system (WinServer2012 and
  WinServer2016) by the installer so that accounts from the local
  groups Administrators or Users have write/delete rights in the folder
  `%ProgramData%\<MyFirm>\<MyApp>` **without** 'Run as Administrator' (UAC on/off) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for reference, [the UAC policy settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd835564(v=ws.10)) - run `secpol.msc => Local Policies => Security Options`. Should not be needed since you don't seem to elevate your app. Just in case you use that "elevate to highest" option - that I have never tried.

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE**: [Setting Permissions in Windows Installer: MSILockPermissionsEX and ISLockPermissions](https://blogs.flexera.com/installtalk/2010/11/setting-permissions-in-windows-installer-msilockpermissionsex-and-islockpermissions/) (using Installshield).

---

***Permission Inspection***: What are the actual permissions showing on the folder? You can use `Windows Explorer => Properties => Security => Advanced => Double click user / group to see detailed access`. Check for differences between the systems that work and don't work.

If that is not good enough maybe try SysInternals' [**AccessEnum**](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/sysinternals/downloads/accessenum) or [**AccessChk**](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk) tools to show details about the permissions defined for the object in question.

***Privilege Inspection***: I would also use [**Process Explorer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to check what **NT Privileges** your process runs with - just to check for any differences ("*torpedoes full spread*" in sci-fi terms - as in "*what the heck are we doing*" - can't hurt). I don't really think this should affect things - **privileges** and **permissions** are different (privileges apply system-wide - such as changing system-time, log on as a service, etc... - permissions are defined for securable objects such as files and folders).

- Launch Process Explorer
- Double click your application process (if it launches)
- Go to "Security" tab and look at lower box:

[image: Process Explorer]

---

***Logging***: Did you do proper logging? If not, [install and create a verbose log file](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm). And [maybe check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417893/msi-installation-log-says-note-1-2205-2-3-error/25435817#25435817). And [a more elaborate version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385973/in-use-files-not-updated-by-msi-installer-visual-studio-installer-project/51387298#51387298) with more hints on understanding the log entries.