# WiX Toolset PermissionEx Problem - App Does Not Run After Installation

Tags: c#, wpf, wix

I have an application in Wpf/C# and I created an installer with the WiX Toolset. The installer works on all tested computers, it does not display any error messages. However, on some machines, the application does not run after installation, even with an administrator user. I believe it's some permission problem, but I'm not sure. How do I give permissions to the current user?

UPDATE:
So far the problem has only occurred on two machines with Windows 10 Home. I thought it might be the InstallerVersion that I set.

Below are the most relevant code snippets.

Any help is very welcome. Thank you.

```
<Product Id="{2A173950-... }"
       Codepage="UTF-8"
       Name="Xyz"
       Language="1033"
       Version="1.0"
       Manufacturer="Xyz Software"
       UpgradeCode="{8B843496-... }">

<Package InstallerVersion="301"
         Compressed="yes"
         InstallScope="perMachine"
         Manufacturer="Xyz Software"
         Description="Xyz Installer"
         Keywords="Practice,Installer,MSI"
         Comments="(c) 2018, Xyz Software" />

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Xyz Installer" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ApplicationComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="DataComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SavedFilesEmptyFolder" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="StartMenuComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="DesktopComponents" />
</Feature>
```

```
<Fragment>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <!--Program Files Folder-->
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="Xyz Software" >
      <Directory Id="ApplicationFolder" Name="Xyz" >
        <Directory Id="DataFolder" Name="Data" >
          <Directory Id="SavedFilesFolder" Name="Saved Files" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <!--Start Menu-->
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="StartMenuFolder" Name="Xyz" />
  </Directory>
  <!--Desktop-->
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
</Directory>
```

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ApplicationComponents" Directory="ApplicationFolder">
  <Component Id="CmpXyzExe" Guid="{1EA7372D-... }">
    <File Id="FilXyzExe" Source="Xyz.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
  <Component Id="CmpSetPermissionsApp" Guid="{36CDCE9A-... }" >
    <CreateFolder>
      <util:PermissionEx User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes" />
      <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericAll="yes" />
    </CreateFolder>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>

<ComponentGroup Id="DataComponents" Directory="DataFolder">
  <Component Id="CmpXyzDic" Guid="{A32B6F47-... }">
    <File Id="FilXyzDic" Source="Xyz.dic"  />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>


<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="StartMenuComponents" Directory="StartMenuFolder">
  <Component Id="CmpStartMenuShortcuts" Guid="{818AD65E-... }">
    <CreateFolder />
    <Shortcut Id="SctApplication"
              Name="Xyz"
              Target="[ApplicationFolder]Xyz.exe" />
    <Shortcut Id="SctUninstall"
              Name="Uninstall Xyz"
              Description="Uninstalls Xyz and all of its components"
              Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
              Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="RmvStartMenuComponents"
                  On="uninstall" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\Xyz"
                   Name="installed"
                   Type="integer"
                   Value="1"
                   KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="DesktopComponents" Directory="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="CmpDesktopShortcuts" Guid="{4FC34354-... }">
    <Shortcut Id="SctApplicationDesktop"
              Name="Xyz"
              Target="[ApplicationFolder]Xyz.exe" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="RmvDesktopComponents"
                  On="uninstall" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\Xyz"
                   Name="installed"
                   Type="integer"
                   Value="1"
                   KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the application to start immediately after finishing the installation? Or do you mean that the user can't launch the installed application from start menu or .exe after the installation?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear Hemaolle, I wanted to say that the user can not start the application after installation.

Comment: Going to look later, but maybe just [verify the permissions as attempted explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087656/setup-cannot-set-correct-folder-permission-for-programdata-myfirm-myapp-on-win/53108569#53108569).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Permissions***: As commented above, maybe do a quick check to see if the permissions are applied correctly as described here: [Checking
>   permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087656/setup-cannot-set-correct-folder-permission-for-programdata-myfirm-myapp-on-win/53108569#53108569).
>
> ***Runtime Dependency / Requirement***: If this happens on very few machines one would think the cause to be a runtime requirement that is
>   not met. Are you sure you have the visual studio C++ runtime installed
>   on the computers in question? Or some other runtime requirement?

***Debugging Launch Issues***: There are several older answers with suggestions on debugging. Now that I look at them they are so similar that I need to stop repeating myself in different flavors:

- [**Application Launch Issues Check List**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623588/windows-application-startup-error-exception-code-0xe0434352/49637913#49637913) (list of ideas)
- [**Launch debug binaries and attach debugger - and dependency scanner tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939079/which-winform-project-files-should-be-packed-up-into-the-installer/51940598#51940598) (Which winform project files should be packed up into the installer)
- [How exactly does the WiX 'Service Install' work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801518/how-exactly-does-the-wix-service-install-work-internally/49802335#49802335)
- [wix c# app doesn't launch after installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263983/wix-c-sharp-app-doesnt-launch-after-installing/52264406#52264406)
- [Visual Studio installer fails on AspNetDiagnosticPack.msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350#49987350)
- [The setup process in windows fails access denied when trying to create "uc.micro" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431725/the-setup-process-in-windows-fails-access-denied-when-trying-to-create-uc-micro/48433935#48433935)
- [Create a .config folder in the user folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695746/create-a-config-folder-in-the-user-folder/48697347#48697347)
- [EXE file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651252/exe-file-is-not-working/48654444#48654444)

***Procedure***: In brief I would try to determine if there is a missing runtime. You can use `procmon.exe` or `dependency walker` to check for this. You can also use the debugging approach described above where you build debug binaries and connect to the binaries during launch. Provided the binary gets off the ground at all.

Comment: Using Dependency Walker, I discovered a few missing libraries.

Comment: That would do it. Could be more of course. Nicely stated question by the way. I forgot to upvote it before. Let me do that now.