# WPF application crashes when I launch

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje, vsinstaller

I used 'Microsoft Visual Studio Installer' to create a MSI for a legacy c# WPF application.

After I install, I see this error BELOW. Do I have the wrong net framework installed ?

Faulting application name: MyDesktop.UI.exe, version: 1.20.7097.18607, time stamp: 0x5cfa9cce
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3416.0, time stamp: 0x5cabfd2c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0045510d
Faulting process id: 0x93c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d51d5595e74050
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ASD\Microsoft.Support.UnifiedDesktop.UI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: b26b4f9f-2e97-434b-b605-fa95ba4974ac
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Got this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

***Source Code?***: I assume you don't have the source code and can't **`1)`** just step-through the launch sequence or **`2)`** attach to debug binaries deployed to final installation location? Just checking.

***No Source Code***: Without source available, I usually use **`3)`** [**`ProcMon.exe`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor launch problems ([quick sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746076/registering-a-cpp-dll-into-com-after-installation-using-wix-msi-installer/47792474#47792474) - and [Hanselman has a video on ProcMon.exe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjKNx41Ubxw)) and **`4)`** I enable any available **`logging`** and / or **`application.exe debug modes`**. **`5)`** Sometimes I assemble all files in a folder on the desktop and try to run from there (generally no permission or access denied problems).

***Common Problems***: Very often problems relate to [**`lacking permission`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108569/129130) or **`missing runtimes`** (for example: `.Net`, `Java`, `VC++ Runtime`, `etc...`) and the usual **`configuration errors`** found in `config files` (`ini`, `xml`) and the `registry` (`wrong paths`, `URLs`, `settings`, `etc...`) - obvious, just mentioning.

> ***"Ideas List"***: Here is a long "ideas list" of potential culprit causes: [**Launch Debugging** - "torpedos full spread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512998/desktop-applicaton-not-opening-after-installation-in-client-system/53530377#53530377). Please do
>   check this one. Links to older versions of the list can be found
>   below.

---

> ***Error Code***: Looking up the error code ([**"The Magic Number Database"**](https://www.magnumdb.com/)) it seems to be an access violation: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0xc0000005
>
> - [**Checking Error Codes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572537/msiexec-returns-negative-number/52573312#52573312) - several tools and approaches

---

Here are some resources:

- ***Launch Debugging Ideas List***: [Windows Application Startup Error Exception code: 0xe0434352](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623588/windows-application-startup-error-exception-code-0xe0434352/49637913#49637913) (older version, similar to the one linked to above).
- ***Dependency Scanners***: [Various tools to debug dependency issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939079/which-winform-project-files-should-be-packed-up-into-the-installer) (many different tools can help launch debugging, here are some of the most common ones).
- ***Permissions & Runtimes***: [WiX Toolset PermissionEx Problem - App Does Not Run After Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354907/wix-toolset-permissionex-problem-app-does-not-run-after-installation/53364536#53364536) (top part of answer only).