# Check if .NETCore is installed using CustomAction with Wix

Tags: c#, .net-core, installation, wix, custom-action

I want to cancel the installation if the NetCore 3.1 (preview) is not installed

I create this CustomAction :

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WixCustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CheckDotNetCore31Installed(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Begin CheckDotNetCore31Installed");

            RegistryKey lKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost");

            var version = (string)lKey.GetValue("Version");

            session["DOTNETCORE31"] = version == "3.1.0-preview3.19553.2" ? "1" : "0";

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the WXS file :

```
<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

   <Product ...>

  (...)

    <Property Id="DOTNETCORE31">0</Property>

    <Condition Message="You must first install the .NET Core 3.1 Runtime">
      Installed OR DOTNETCORE31="1"
    </Condition>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="Check.NetCore" Before="LaunchConditions">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Binary Id="WixCA.dll" SourceFile="$(var.WixCustomAction.TargetDir)$(var.WixCustomAction.TargetName).CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="Check.NetCore" BinaryKey="WixCA.dll" DllEntry="CheckDotNetCore31Installed" Execute="immediate"  />
  </Fragment>
```

And this is where I have a problem because I always get the warning message.
An idea ? thanks

Comment: Please add the warning message.

Comment: for me it's the line "<Condition Message="You must first install the .NET Core 3.1 Runtime">".  If you ask the question, it shows that I didn't understand anything :(

Comment: It would not be `<![CDATA[Installed OR (DOTNETCORE31 = 1)]]>` for testing value ?

Comment: The syntax seems more correct but for this problem the result does not change :/

Answer (score 2):

maybe it will be better to check .net core version using cmd with
`dotnet --version` command, to avoid windows architecture dependencies

custom action sample for this case:

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CheckVersion(Session session)
    {
       var minVersion = new Version(3, 1, 1);
        var command = "/c dotnet --version";// /c is important here
        var output = string.Empty;
        using (var p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = command,
                UseShellExecute = false,                    
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            };
            p.Start();
            while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                output += $"{p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()}{Environment.NewLine}";
            }
            p.WaitForExit();
            if (p.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                session["DOTNETCORE1"] = "0";
                return ActionResult.Success;
                //throw new Exception($"{p.ExitCode}:{ p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()}");
            }

            //you can implement here your own comparing algorithm
            //mine will not work with -perview string, but in this case you can just 
            //replace all alphabetical symbols with . using regex, for example
            var currentVersion = Version.Parse(output);
            session["DOTNETCORE1"] = (currentVersion < minVersion) ? "0" : "1";
            
            return ActionResult.Success;
         }
```

UPDATE:
As Adam mentioned, I was wrong with that snippet - it works only for SDKs.
Here's another one to get runtimes:

```
    static readonly List<string> runtimes = new List<string>()
    {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App",//.NET Runtime
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",//ASP.NET Core Runtime
        "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",//.NET Desktop Runtime
    };

    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CheckVersion(Session session)
    {
        var minVersion = new Version(3, 1, 1);
        var command = "/c dotnet --list-runtimes";// /c is important here
        var output = string.Empty;
        using (var p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = command,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            };
            p.Start();
            while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                output += $"{p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()}{Environment.NewLine}";
            }
            p.WaitForExit();
            if (p.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                session["DOTNETCORE1"] = "0";
                return ActionResult.Success;
                //throw new Exception($"{p.ExitCode}:{ p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()}");
            }
            session["DOTNETCORE1"] = (GetLatestVersionOfRuntime(runtimes[0], output) < minVersion) ? "0" : "1";
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }

    private static Version GetLatestVersionOfRuntime(string runtime, string runtimesList)
    {
        var latestLine = runtimesList.Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList().Where(x => x.Contains(runtime)).OrderBy(x => x).LastOrDefault();
        if (latestLine != null)
        {
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)+");
            Match m = pattern.Match(latestLine);
            string versionValue = m.Value;
            if (Version.TryParse(versionValue, out var version))
            {
                return version;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: In general I like this idea but `dotnet --version` isn't available for .NET Core runtimes, only SDKs. The runtime does support `dotnet --list-runtimes` but parsing is a bit tedious.

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right. that time I tested it only on developer's machine. updated post with parsing of `dotnet --list-runtimes`

Answer (score 1):

> ***Debugging***: Are you attaching the debugger to your custom action so you
>   can see what is going on there? I bet it is not setting your property correctly. `The custom action might not be running at all`? Show a message box to smoke test that? More involved (attaching Visual Studio debugger):
>
> - [**Direct video link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayeBB97_NwA) (please watch it, very short and nice -
>     from the [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) guys)
> - [**Answer on debugging**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878332/wixsharp-debug-custom-action-in-console/52880033#52880033) (skim if not using attached debugger please)
> - [See debugging section here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (more comprehensive, more links)

***LaunchCondition***: In an MSI database launch conditions are represented by records in the [LaunchCondition table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/launchcondition-table). This table has two columns. *The **Condition column** contains an expression which must evaluate to **True** for installation to continue*:

[image: MSI]

> ***Conclusion***: *`So your condition does not evaluate to true properly`*. What is the
>   actual value of **`DOTNETCORE31`**? I bet it is **`0`**. Double check
>   please. Easiest way is obviously to set it to **`1`** instead of **`0`** directly - and then compile again and test. Hard coding temporarily like this:
>
> ```
> <Property Id="DOTNETCORE31">1</Property>
> ```

---

***Links***: Here are some previous answer on launch conditions and other topics:

- ***Previous Answer***: **[Check if prerequisites are installed before installing a windows installer package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121149/check-if-prerequisites-are-installed-before-installing-a-windows-installer-packa/55183152#55183152)**
- ***C++ Custom Action***: [Interrupt installation when custom action returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925087/interrupt-installation-when-custom-action-returns-error/54929785#54929785) (C++ is great for **`minimal dependencies`** and **`debugability`** - it runs native, no layers, emulation and stuff that can break)
- [How to execute conditional custom action on install and modify only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370505/how-to-execute-conditional-custom-action-on-install-and-modify-only/52377800#52377800) (basic WiX markup for VBScript custom actions)
- [Windows Installer Deferred execution - how can we log the custom actions running in deferred mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572168/windows-installer-deferred-execution-how-can-we-log-the-custom-actions-running)

---

***WiX Custom Action***: You have the basic markup for calling the custom action? Check the compiled MSI with `Orca` to see if there are entries in the `Binary`, `CustomAction` and `InstallExecuteSequence` and `InstallUISequence` tables. Some mock-up WiX markup ([pillage gihub.com for samples?](https://github.com/search?q=%3CBinary%20Id%3D%20%3CInstallUISequence%3E%20%3CCustom%20Action%3D&type=Code)):

```
<Binary Id="CustomActions" SourceFile="C:\Test.CA.dll" />

<...>

<CustomAction Id="CustomAction1" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="CustomAction1"/>

<...>

<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="CustomAction1" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallUISequence>

<...>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CustomAction1" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

***GUI & Silent Install***: Obviously you could also run the custom action from a dialog event - like a button click - but that would make it NOT run in silent mode. The GUI is skipped in silent mode so you need to run the custom action in the `InstallExecuteSequence` as well as the GUI.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very informative message. It helped me a lot. I was able to debug my CustomAction and understood where the problem came from : it didn't read the 64bit registry !

Comment: Ah, the classic bitness problem. Always high on the list and I should have mentioned it. I am not sure this registry read is the best approach to detect .NET Core, but that is another story. What when the next version comes along? Might have a look later. There are built-in measures to detect the main .NET framework (old school .NET).

Comment: I waiting for this https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6099 but we'll have to wait for the.NETCore to come out of the preview

Comment: Ah, shows how outdated I am. Thanks for the link! Maybe you can do a "higher than" check rather than just check for a specific version number? I haven't studied this much.

Comment: Very good idea!  As soon as a new preview is available I will check how the version number evolves

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Stein Asmul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129130/stein-%C3%85smul), I was able to debug my CustomAction. Here is the code that works :

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WixCustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CheckDotNetCore31Installed(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Begin CheckDotNetCore31Installed");

            RegistryKey localMachine64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            RegistryKey lKey = localMachine64.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost\", false);

            var version = (string)lKey.GetValue("Version");

            session["DOTNETCORE1"] = version == "3.1.0-preview3.19553.2" ? "1" : "0";

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When using `SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost` there is a problem;  If the admin uninstalls .net core, the registry value remains and does not reflect what is actually installed.