# Downloading .NET 6.0 from the web with Wix ToolSet

Tags: installation, wix, .net-runtime

I am developing a wix setup project that creates an installer for my application.

My app requires `.net 6.0 desktop runtime` to run properly, I couldn't find any documentation on how to install it from the web after checking if it is available on the client PC, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930065/check-if-netcore-is-installed-using-customaction-with-wix/62679569#62679569) for the checking for a version part but I wasn't able to find any help on installing the runtime from the web and running it .

Comment: You can either handle it via a custom action. Or package the .NET 6 msi along with your installer.