# Where can i find msi table column properties?

Tags: sql, database, windows-installer

```
CREATE TABLE `Directory` 
(
     `Directory` CHAR(72) NOT NULL, 
     `Directory_Parent` CHAR(72),
     `DefaultDir` CHAR(255) NOT NULL LOCALIZABLE PRIMARY KEY `Directory`
)
```

Where can I find the information about the datatypes used in the above create statement?

I need info on all the msi tables.

Comment: Have you looked at the [official Microsoft documentation on Windows Installer?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference)

Comment: CHAR is a data type used to store character data. Blank padded to its full length.

Comment: @marc_s, yes I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***MSI SDK***: This section in the MSI SDK lists the built-in MSI tables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/database-tables - see the Orca section below for more technical information: the file **`"orca.dat"`** in the Orca installation folder holds the schema.

***Technicalities***: A few things first: The tables starting with underscore: **`_`** such as **`_Validation`** and **`_Streams`** are special tables - most of which are not visible from within Orca.

- The [_Validation table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/-validation-table) is a system table that essentially shows the database schema. It is used during [**MSI database validation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793670/129130) **(recommended read)**. You can see the different: [Database Column Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/column-data-types).

  - Validation runs a series of checks on the MSI database and its content to check for common problems as well as consistency with the database schema.
  - The database checks are implemented in **`*.CUB files`**. They can contain runnable code against the database - for example VBScript files. Open the **`*.CUB files`** with Orca to see the content.
  - Validation can be invoked interactively from Orca or via the command line.
- The [_Streams table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/-streams-table) is a temporary table which is involved with SQL statements. Same thing with [_Storages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/-storages-table). And there are a few more such system tables.

***Orca***: Orca is the SDK tool for viewing and modifying MSI database files.

- You can use  Orca to open an MSI and select **`Tables => Export Tables...`** Specify an output directory and select to export all tables. You get **`*.idt`** files with description of the content. Open in Notepad or any text editor.
- In the Orca installation folder there is a file called **`"orca.dat"`**. This is apparently the database schema for MSI files. You can use the **`"Export Tables"`** approach for this file after you open it in Orca. Just export all tables and this should be all valid MSI tables exported to **`*.idt`** format. There will be headers which should indicate the datatypes:

  [image: IDT Files]

***MSI SDK VBScript***: Included in the SDK installed with Visual Studio you will find a number of VBScript files that show a number of techniques you can use when dealing with MSI files. The [Windows Installer Scripting Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-scripting-examples). Look under: **`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86`** - replace with the current numbers for the penultimate folder name. [Quick preview of the files here](https://gist.github.com/eladkarako/083fc3f2d6e066f44a16d50dca006a05).