# WIX Toolset 3.11: Including es-419 language DLLs gives ICE03 error. (.NET 4.8)

Tags: .net, wix, translation

I have .NET solution with fully working WIX project that builds installer. We have recently introduced translation resources for latin spanish language (es-419) generated by SDL Passolo. The problem is that upon build we now receive errors like the following:

`ICE03: Invalid Language Id; Table: File, Column: Language, Key(s): <file_key_here>`

Languages are included in compilation via `LanguageDirectories.wxs`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="de" Name="de" />
            <Directory Id="en" Name="en" />
            <Directory Id="es_419" Name="es-419" />
    </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I went through WIX documentation but didn't find anything that could help me with this error. I've used ILSpy to inspect the DLLs but they do not seem to have any language id the error speaks of.

Comment: [Please see if this old answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793670/129130). Open the MSI with Orca and inspect the File table.

Comment: Maybe a problem with command line, or project settings? (invalid language specification when building MSI). The code fragment you posted looks okay to me... How do you specify the target MSI language?

Comment: Yes, probably something simple. However, do try to open the MSI with Orca and see what is actually in there. There tend to be surprises with MSI.

Comment: I've checked the .msi with orca, language code for failing files is `22538`, which seems to be correct for `Spanish (Latin America)` language.
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/development/Internationalization/language

Comment: Forgot to add: installer itself is not localized. Included resource dlls are for application itself.